# "message": "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0", "stack": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"

Tags: graphql

```js
const express = require('express');
const {graphqlHTTP} = require('express-graphql');
const schema = require('./schema/schema');

const app = express();

app.get('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    graphiql:true,
    schema: schema
}))

app.listen(4000,()=>{
    console.log("listining to port 4000..")
})
```

```js
const graphql = require('graphql');

const{
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLID,
    GraphQLString,
    GraphQLInt,
    GraphQLSchema
} = graphql

const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'user',
    description: 'Documentation for User...',
    fields: ()=>({
        id: {type: GraphQLString},
        name: {type: GraphQLString},
        age: {type: GraphQLInt}
    })
});

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    description: 'description',
    fields: {
        user: {
            type: UserType,
            args: {id: {type: GraphQLString}},
            resolve(parent,args){
                let user = {
                    id: '345',
                    age: 34,
                    name: 'Aman'
                }
                return user;
            }      
        }
    }
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQuery
})
```

Above are my code and I am getting this error :

**"message": "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0",

"stack":  "SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0"**

Can anyone tell me how I resolved this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what google says?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of seems like you're seeing this error on your client-side application? On a side note, you didn't add much details of what you're doing to get this error, where you're seeing it, and what you think is causing it, so I can only go off of what you've provided in terms of what your set up is.

This seems like you're getting an HTML response from your server where you're expecting JSON. Typically, with GraphQL this may happen because you're sending a GET request (which may bring up the GraphiQL explorer) rather than a POST request.

Your GraphQL client code should make a POST request and you should ensure that it sends a header to accept `application/json` responses.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is really helped me.